# Tkinter - Problem after add background in my project

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

**Hi Guys I have Problem after add background in my project, I don't see anything but after resize I see background: I don't want to use ttk in my object.**

**This is my code:**

```
from tkinter import (Button, Label, Frame)


class HomeFrame(Frame):  # Inherit Frame class
"""Application main interface"""

  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.root = parent  # Define internal variable root
    self.root.configure(background='green')
    self.home_page()

  def home_page(self):
    """Load control"""

    Label(self, text="First name").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
    Full_name = Button(self, text="Get Full name")
    Full_name.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=20)
    Label(self, text="Last name").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
    hello = Button(self, text="hello")
    hello.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=20)
```

**This is Result:**

[Interface without resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH7s4.png)

**After Resize:**

[Interface After Resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdLQa.png)

Comment: You probably want `self.configure(...`

Comment: Tkinter widgets are always fully opaque, and do not inherit anything (such as background color) from the containing widget or window.  So what you're seeing is the default background of all of your individual widgets: none of the window's background is visible, because its natural size is just big enough to hold all the widgets.

Comment: @jasonharper thank you It's work
How can I use Style Theme without using ttk in this project, Like : ttk.Label or ttk.Button

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import (Button, Label, Frame)


class HomeFrame(Frame):  # Inherit Frame class
  """Application main interface"""

   def __init__(self, parent=None):
       Frame.__init__(self, parent)
       self.root = parent  # Define internal variable root
       self.root.configure(background='green')
       self.config(background='green')
       self.home_page()

  def home_page(self):
    """Load control"""

     Label(self, text="First name").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
     Full_name = Button(self, text="Get Full name")
     Full_name.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=20)
     Label(self, text="Last name").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
     hello = Button(self, text="hello")
     hello.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=20)
```